# Reference an EF5 project from an EF6 project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to use a project that was written and built using Entity Framework 5 as a reference in a project that uses Entity Framework 6?  When doing so, I get "Method not found" errors on functionality that has been deprecated in EF6, but that works just fine when used in the EF5 project as a standalone project.

A call like this:

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery()
```

throws an error of:

```
{"Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(System.String, System.Object[])'."} System.Exception {System.MissingMethodException}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example of what is not working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am trying to do the same.